# use regex to find sentences containing duplicated words

Tags: python, regex

I've tried below.

```
import re
sentences = "Glitches happened happened happened. Things go back to normal again."
print([re.findall(r"(\w+)\s\1", s) for s in sentences.split('.')])
```

I am wondering how to print the entire sentence(s) that contain duplicated words.

Comment: So your question is how to make the regex match the _sentence_?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option, using a list comprehension along with `re.search`:

```py
inp = "Glitches happened happened happened. Things go back to normal again."
sentences = re.split(r'(?<=\.)\s+', inp)
duplicates = [s for s in sentences if re.search(r'\b(\S+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)', s)]
print(duplicates)
```

This prints:

```
['Glitches happened happened happened.']
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, using `re.search` function of Python's `re` library.

```
>>> import re
>>> sentences = "Glitches happened happened happened. Things go back to normal again."
>>> print ( [el for el in sentences.split('. ') if re.search(r'\b(\w+)\s+\1\b', el)] )
    ['Glitches happened happened happened']
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As workaround, you can try:

```
import re

sentences = "Glitches happened happened happened. Things go back to normal again. And once again again again."
print([s for s in sentences.split('.') if re.search(r"\b(\w+)\s+\1\b", s)])
```

result:

```
['Glitches happened happened happened', ' And once again again again']
```